# Factory with companion object where each type of object takes a common parameter

Tags: scala, factory, companion-object

I have a class like this -

```
class Cache (
  tableName: String,
  TTL: Int) {
  // Creates a cache
}
```

I have a companion object that returns different types of caches. It has functions that require a base table name and can construct the cache.

```
object Cache {
   def getOpsCache(baseTableName: String): Cache = {
    new Cache(s"baseTableName_ops", OpsTTL);
  }

  def getSnapshotCache(baseTableName: String): Cache = {
    new Cache(s"baseTableName_snaps", SnapshotTTL);
  }

  def getMetadataCache(baseTableName: String): Cache = {
    new Cache(s"baseTableName_metadata", MetadataTTL);
  }
}
```

The object does a few more things and the `Cache` class has more parameters, which makes it useful to have a companion object to create different types of `Cache`s. The `baseTableName` parameter is same for all of the caches. Is there a way in which I can pass this parameter only once and then just call the functions to get different types of caches ?

Alternative to this is to create a factory class and pass the `baseTableName` parameter to constructor and then call the functions. But I am wondering if it could be done in any way with the Companion object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to put your factory in a `case class`:

```
case class CacheFactory(baseTableName: String) {

  lazy val getOpsCache: Cache = 
     Cache(s"baseTableName_ops", OpsTTL)

  lazy val getSnapshotCache =
     Cache(s"baseTableName_snaps", SnapshotTTL)

  lazy val getMetadataCache =
    Cache(s"baseTableName_metadata", MetadataTTL) 
}
```

As I like `case classes` I changed your Cache also to a `case class`:

```
case class Cache(tableName: String, TTL: Int)
```

As you can see I adjusted your ***Java*** code to correct ***Scala*** code.

If you want to put it in the `companion object`, you could use `implicits`, like:

```
object Cache {

  def getOpsCache(implicit baseTableName: String): Cache = 
     Cache(s"baseTableName_ops", OpsTTL)

  def getSnapshotCache(implicit baseTableName: String) =
     Cache(s"baseTableName_snaps", SnapshotTTL)

  def getMetadataCache(implicit baseTableName: String) =
    Cache(s"baseTableName_metadata", MetadataTTL) 
}
```

Then your client looks like:

```
implicit val baseTableName: String = "baseName"

cache.getSnapshotCache
cache.getMetadataCache
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider creating algebraic data type like so

```
sealed abstract class Cache(tablePostfix: String, ttl: Int) {
  val tableName = s"baseTableName_$tablePostfix"
}
case object OpsCache extends Cache("ops", 60)
case object SnapshotCache extends Cache("snaps", 120)
case object MetadataCache extends Cache("metadata", 180)

OpsCache.tableName // res0: String = baseTableName_ops
```